# My computer is turning off and on over and over?

Tags: bios, power-supply, hardware-failure

I was wondering if any of you know why my computer is turning off and on every 2-6 seconds when it starts? It happens when I turn off my computer then try to turn it on again. I got it to work for now, but Im afraid it will happen again when I turn it off.

Here is what I checked:

- Plugged it into a different outlet.
- Switched out the power cable + different outlet.
- I opened the computer and checked to the best of my ability that all the cables were plugged into the motherboard and power supply.

I'm thinking maybe its something wrong with power supply or motherboard worst case scenario?

Here is what I got when it booted up finally (if it applies to this problem, idk. First time I seen that).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From casual observation of your screenshot, this seems to be an issue with your motherboard. The [BIOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) (which is essentially to booting the PC) seems to be having a severe issue. Most likely, your PC is taking repeated actions to try and boot and failing (hence the restarts) before finally "restoring" from the [backup BIOS](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dualbios.htm).

While such an issue could arise from a botched BIOS update or a virus, at a guess (since this appears to be happening even after supposed restoration), the likely culprit seems to plausibily be a bad chip on the motherboard.

Comment: Your welcome. Sorry this is happening. :/